# How would we add Drupal Core modules as dependencies on custom modules post 8.6.2?

Tags: 8, hooks, upgrading

We recently updated to [Drupal Core 8.6.2](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/releases/8.6.2) and noticed there are changes to `module dependencies`. We are noticing that `drupal:` is added before the module names. We were unable to find any documentation that further explains it.

How would we add Drupal Core modules as dependencies on custom modules post 8.6.2?

**mymodule.info.yml example before 8.6.2**

```
type: module
name: my module
description: my custom module
package: 8.x
core: 8.x
dependencies:
  - field
  - image
```

**mymodule.info.yml example after 8.6.2**

```
type: module
name: my module
description: my custom module
package: 8.x
core: 8.x
dependencies:
  - drupal:field
  - drupal:image
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're referencing a recent change in a core module, it was a style/formatting change.

Adding namespaces for dependencies has been in core [for a while](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2205271). The `{project}:{module}` format is a better practice for removing ambiguity in the event of module/project machine name overlap, but both will work.

For documentation reference, see [*Let Drupal 8 know about your module with an .info.yml file*](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/let-drupal-8-know-about-your-module-with-an-infoyml-file) under the example section for `dependencies`:

> > `dependencies` - A list of other modules your module depends on. Dependencies should be namespaced in the format `{project}:{module}`, where `{project}` is the project name as it appears in the Drupal.org URL (e.g. drupal.org/project/views) and `{module}` is the module's machine name. Dependencies can also include version restrictions, for example `webform:webform (>=8.x-5.x)`. Note that if your module has dependencies on other contributed modules or libraries, these should be declared in the module's composer.json file.