# How do I check if TwigTweak is enabled before declaring a function in a template?

Tags: theming

I am cretaing a theme which uses the twigtweak module to display some views/blocks in some of the templates.

If a person enables the theme before enabling twigtweak module they get an error.
For example if I put the following in a template, the site gets a php error 'drupal_entity is an unknown function'

```
{{ drupal_entity('block_content', 1) }}
```

So I try

```
{% if drupal_entity ?? false %}
    {{ drupal_entity('block_content', 1) }}
{% else %}
    <p>You should enable Twig Tweak module for this functionality</p>
{% endif %}
```

But I am still getting similar errors.
How can I check if Twig Tweak is enabled or if the Twig Tweak function is valid/exists?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

On Drupal 8.9.x and successive Drupal versions, a theme can define its dependencies from modules. When that theme is installed, Drupal core will require that module to be installed, before allowing the theme installation. This means that when a theme template file is used, the require to use it.

[Themes can declare dependencies on modules](https://www.drupal.org/node/2937955) gives more details, but essentially that is done as it is done with modules. In the .info.yml file for the theme, it is sufficient to add lines like the following ones. (Replace `<module>` with the module name, name-spaced, for example `drupal:user` for the User module that is part of Drupal core, or `twig_tweak:twig_tweak` for the [Twig Tweak](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak) module.)

```yaml
dependencies:
  - <module>
```

If instead you want the theme to optionally depend on that module, you need to implement a preprocess function that is used for that template file. Since the question does not make clear which template file is used, I will make an example that is valid for the *user.html.twig* template file, but that can be adapted to other template files. (Replace `<theme_name>` with the theme machine name.)

```php
function <theme_name>_preprocess_user(&$variables) {
  $variables['twig_tweak'] = \Drupal::moduleHandler()->moduleExists('twig_tweak');
}
```

Then, the template file should check the value of that variable.

```
{% if twig_tweak %}
  {{ drupal_entity('block_content', 1) }}
{% else %}
  { # Show the content in a different way #}
{% endif %}
```

Since that module is an optional dependency, users should not see a message telling them to install a module when the module is not installed, which would probably be seen even from users who cannot install new modules on that site. Instead, the template file should shown alternative content, or show the same content in a different way.

If the same variable is required from more template files, instead of a preprocess function that is called for a single template file, I would implement `<theme_name>_preprocess()`, which is called for every template file.

Comment: Hi, thanks but I am trying to make it optional. So added functionality if the module is enabled but the theme still works if it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

If your theme depends on a module to function you should add the module as a dependancy in your themes .info.yml file. e.g.:

```
dependencies:
  - drupal:twig_tweak
```

Then people won't be able to install your theme without it

Comment: That module is not part of Drupal core.

Comment: I know but what's your point? That's how the module is named in Drupal's package list and it's how to add it as a dependency

Comment: With `drupal:twig_tweak`, Drupal will search the module in the Drupal core modules. That is not the namespaced name of that module, which must follow the `<project name>:<module name>` schema.

Comment: Feel free to try what I suggested. I have and it worked perfectly well with a contrib module.

Comment: It works when the module is already installed. If Drupal needs to give a link to the missing module, it needs the correct project name.

Comment: How to define dependencies is explained in [How would we add Drupal Core modules as dependencies on custom modules post 8.6.2?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/272106/how-would-we-add-drupal-core-modules-as-dependencies-on-custom-modules-post-8-6) which also quotes documentation with an example for a module that is not part of Drupal core.